# What is so different about these functions?

Tags: function, sml, smlnj

I've got a function:

```
fn x => x
```

Now, the parameter x is applied to both real and int (e.g. (x:real)). What is different and what is the same about the two functions even though they seem to do effectively the same thing:

```
1. fn (x:int) => x;
2. fn (x:real) => x;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three are the identity function, but the second two are not polymorphic.

The non-polymorphic versions don't do exactly the same – one has type `int -> int`, the other `real -> real`, so they can only be applied to respectively `int` and `real`.

Example:

```
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.79 [built: Wed Oct  7 00:59:52 2015]
fn (x:int) => x;
val it = fn : int -> int
- fn (x:real) => x;
val it = fn : real -> real 
- (fn (x:int) => x) 3;
val it = 3 : int
- (fn (x:int) => x) 3.0;
stdIn:2.1-2.22 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: int
  operand:         real
  in expression:
    (fn x : int => x) 3.0
- (fn (x:real) => x) 3;
stdIn:1.2-1.22 Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload conflict]
  operator domain: real
  operand:         [int ty]
  in expression:
    (fn x : real => x) 3
- (fn (x:real) => x) 3.0;
val it = 3.0 : real
```

In contrast, the polymorphic version works with everything:

```
- fn x => x;
val it = fn : 'a -> 'a
- (fn x => x) 3.0;
val it = 3.0 : real
- (fn x => x) 3;
val it = 3 : int
- (fn x => x) "hello";
val it = "hello" : string
- (fn x => x) [1,2,3];
val it = [1,2,3] : int list
```

Answer (score 1):

In 1. and 2., you are not applying the function, you are specifying the type. In order to apply the function, write `(fn x => x) 5` and `fn x => x) 5.0`. When you perform this function application, x is indeed inferred to have the types you write explicitly.

The difference between your two functions below is that they take different types. The similarity between the two functions is that they do the same to their input, namely, they just give it back.

Answer (score 0):

**Both functions take an input of x and output x.**

However, in the first function the input x is **casted** to be of type **int**, whilst the second is casted to be of type **real**.

Therefore the first function is of type `(int -> int)` and the second `(real -> real)`.

Comment: *[Casted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion)* (or type conversion) is the wrong word to use, since it implies that the data representation changes. There is no type conversion going on here.